# Can we handle "ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE - ERR_CONNECTION_RESET - ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED"

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ember.js

Can we handle following errors: `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE`, `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`, `ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED` properly and throw exceptions, maybe in Java, JavaScript or Ember, even jQuery.

I googled it for 15 days, and not appropriate solution. Just need to give proper error messages in above error cases. We are using `XMLHttpRequest` to send request to server in case of file uploads

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in jQuery might do what you're after. More info [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: myData
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //process error here
});
```

Comment: Php is not the Language i tagged, its JAVA, JavaScript, Ember or Jquery. Please read question before replying

Comment: @DeepakNegiSunny The solution he gave you is Javascript, however I must point out that this solution doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use the try...catch syntax in javascript. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch).

```
try {
    //do something
    return true;
} catch (e) {
    //catch error
    return false;
}
```